# Why do I get a syntax error on using offset with jquery 1.8.3 in IE7

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to figure out why I can't scroll back up to the top of page smoothly in IE7.  So I commented out my main code and simply want to see what the value is for target with an offset.  If I place the following code into IE7...

```
function scrollbackup() {
    //setup anchor links for each panel

    //create the links for each section
    var link = '<a class="top" href="#mapSVG">[back to top]</a>';
    $('#mMap a').each(function () {
        $(this).nextUntil('a', 'p').last().after(link);
    });

    //on click, smooth scrolling back to top
    $('a[href*=#]').bind('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = $(this).attr("href");
        var elementTop = $(target).offset().top;
        console.log(elementTop);

        /*
$('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(target).offset().top }, 1000, function() {
location.hash = target;
});
*/
    });
}
```

I get the following error in IE7...

```
SCRIPT5022: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://.../index2.html#mapSVG 
jquery-1.8.3.min.js, line 2 character 59313
```

The error occurs "after" I click the element, and I don't know why it is there to begin with...

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error is jQuery complaining about a bad selector.  My guess is that in your `<a>` tag, you have `http://example.com/index2.html#mapSVG`, instead of just `#mapSVG`.

So when you do `$(target)`, you are passing the whole URL, which is breaking jQuery.

To fix this, use `var target = $(this).prop("hash");` instead.

Comment: Thank you rocket for saving my situation!  I didn't realize I was calling the entire href.  I thought I was only referencing part of it this whole time. I learned some new stuff today.  Thanks again!